# "Skewed" Triangle with asterisks in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I really don't get why all the downvotes:

- I posted my own tentative for it.
- It's well explained what was needed
- I researched the topic extensively, I just found other types of things that for a beginner like me (I started Java a few weeks ago) are quite different.
- The only problem I see here, to be honest, is people downvoting a question because they didn't read the thread, or because they are judging someone as lazy without really knowing what is going on.

I'm learning Java.

I'm trying the thing below, you input a number and it creates a triangle with asterisks. I have it pretty much figured out except that my second loop is not giving me what I think it should be giving (going from a given range to a limit, it's incrementing instead of the opposite, and it's driving me insane).

I can't wrap my mind around why isn't it working as supposed. I just need a fresh pair of eyes on it (and suggestions on how to learn to see those things by myself).

The output for 3 at this moment is:

```
*
**
***
*
**
```

instead of

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

Below is my code for it, with the explanation with what I was trying to do:

```
/*

    Write a program that asks the user to enter the size of a triangle (an integer
    from 1 to 50). Display the triangle by writing lines of asterisks. The first
    line will have one asterisk, the next two, and so on, with each line having one
    more asterisk than the previous line, up to the number entered by the user.
    On the next line write one fewr asterisk and continue by decreasing the number
    of asterisk by 1 for each successive line until only one asterisk is displayed.
    Hint: use nested for loops; the outside loop controls the number of lines to
    write, and the inside loop controls the number of asterisks to display on a line)
    For example, if the user enters 3, the output would be:
    *
    **
    ***
    **
    *

*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangles
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of your triangle (1 to 50):");
        int userInput = kb.nextInt();
        int minus = userInput -1;
        int lineNumber = userInput + minus;
        int half = (lineNumber / 2) + 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= half; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        for (int i = minus; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = minus; j >= i; j--)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the inner loop:

```
for (int i = minus; i >= 1; i--)
{
    System.out.println("");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

While the outer loop is decrementing, the inner loop should be incrementing

The whole code will be:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of your triangle (1 to 50):");
int userInput = kb.nextInt();//3
int minus = userInput -1;//2
int lineNumber = userInput + minus;//5
int half = (lineNumber / 2) + 1;//3

for(int i = 1; i <= half; i++){
    System.out.println("");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
for (int i = minus; i >= 1; i--){
    System.out.println("");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: The output was wrong, it started with 1 asterisk on the second loop.

Comment: By the way... you should make a validation to avoid a number bigger than 50 be introduced... you say _Enter the number of your triangle (1 to 50):_ but you do not perform any kind of validation.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to adjust the "minus" on the inner loop to 1. Now I get it why it wasn't working. I mean, sorta. Have to try it more, but being stuck in a problem for hours in a row without anyone to ask around is pretty tough. Thank you!

Comment: Re: validation, I'm aware, but since the testing isn't for public but a controlled testing performed by someone, it's just to reach what it's intended, in the case at hand, the use of nested-loops. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice short way to do it:

```
private static void test(int n) {
    char[] buf = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(buf, '*');
    for (int row = 1 - n; row < n; row++)
        System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, n - Math.abs(row)));
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(5);
}
```

*Output*

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow, this is really nice!

Comment: Yeah, for printing patterns where top half is mirror of bottom half, with a center line, iterating from `-x` to `+x`, and using `Math.abs()`, is a nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of your triangle (1 to 50): ");
int input = kb.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
  System.out.println();
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
}
for (int i = input - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  System.out.println();
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
}
```

Sample output for `5`:

```
Enter the number of your triangle (1 to 50): 5

*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you mind helping me out wrapping my mind on why my second loop isn't decrementing the amount of asterisks?

Comment: Your stopping condition on the first should stop "earlier", that's why the `i >= 1` change on the loop. The second inner loop gets more "funny" you can go forward or backward but you have to be consistent on the clauses, conditions and termination condition(s).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner loop to this. I tested it and it works great:

```
        //for (int j = minus; j >= i; j--) // <--old line
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) //<--new line
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

You could try

```
  for (int i = minus; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = minus; j >= 0 /* it was i */; j--)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
```

or

```
int add = 1;
int asterics = 1;
while(asterics >0){
   if(asterics == userInput)
   {
      add = -1; // switch to decrement
   }
   for(int i=0;i<asterics;i++){
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   asterics += add;
}
```

Comment: ...that doesn't work